# What is the difference between Android pay and Google wallet?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

Can any one tell briefly about **Android pay** and **Google wallet** ?

Answer (score 0):

Android Pay is an API (Application Program Interface). To define it completely you need to understand that it is not a product which replaces the Google Wallet. It will be integrated within the Google Wallet rather than separately launching as a Product. It can also be called as an API Layer system in Android which will control the in-app and in-store payments.

And Google aims to make it a successful platform, which it also hopes to get integrated with Samsung Pay in the future to expand its reach.

It also uses similar method of NFC like the Apple Pay uses. However, it will also integrate bio-metric system soon.

Answer (score -1):

Android pay is a new framework that offers interfaces for mobile payment to allow you to develope an app for mobile payment. Google Wallet is an already complete moblie payment system that allows youtto store debit cards, credit cards etc. as well as redeeming sales promotions on your phone and make fast and secure payments.

Sources:
http://www.theverge.com/2015/3/2/8131861/android-pay-google-mwc
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Wallet

Answer (score -1):

While more details about Android Pay is still to emerge, from [Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2015/03/02/google-android-pay/)

> Speaking at Mobile World Congress in Barcelona, Google SVP Sundar
>   Pichai confirmed the existence of Android Pay, a platform that will
>   allow developers to build payments into their apps. Don't think of it
>   as a separate app like Wallet (especially as Wallet will utilize the
>   Android Pay platform), but as an OS-level service that makes it easy
>   for app makers or retailers to let you buy things using your Android
>   device.

So, while Google Wallet still remain as a separate app, what it says is that, Android Pay will be a service which companies can incorporate into their apps to enable the users to pay online. It's more like an integration solution to accept payments within other apps.

As per [TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2015/03/02/android-pay-is-real-and-will-give-developers-the-reins-as-an-api/)

> Android Pay sounds like it’ll offer one half of what Apple Pay is on
>   the iPhone, providing users with a way to store their payment
>   information locally, and make it available securely to third-party
>   developer apps via API. Those apps will then determine when and where
>   you can use the payment cards, via store (and perhaps payment
>   provider) specific apps that can be branded however third parties
>   like.
>
> Google’s system will tokenize card numbers, in the same way that Apple
>   Pay and Samsung Pay do, meaning it generates a one-time payment token
>   for transmission to the receiving terminal for each transaction,
>   rather than just offering the user’s static credit card information.
>   This decreases the risk if the transmission is intercepted, since a
>   one-time token with finite expiry is of no use once it’s already been
>   consumed.

You can think of Google Wallet and the first app which uses the Google Pay platform/API.